# Добавил corsConfigurationSource и все равно ошибка "has been blocked by CORS policy"

Tags: spring-security

Пробую подключить в свой проект Spring Security. В качестве фронтенда используется Angular.
Создал класс SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    
    public SecurityConfig(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/api/v1/user/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/auth/api/v1/admin/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider));
    }
}
```

Отправляю запрос из броузера на регистрацию

```
http://localhost:15001/auth/api/v1/user/register
```

и получаю ответ:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:15001/auth/api/v1/user/register' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Согласно документации на Spring добавляю метод corsConfigurationSource:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    
    public SecurityConfig(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/api/v1/user/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/auth/api/v1/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider));
    }
}
```

Отправляю запрос из броузера на регистрацию

```
http://localhost:15001/auth/api/v1/user/register
```

и все равно получаю эту же ошибку

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:15001/auth/api/v1/user/register' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Почему ошибка не пропала?

Я знаю, что есть еще одни способ добавить на контроллер

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200″)
```

Можно так же добавить в заголовок.
но я хочу разобраться почему этот способ не работает.

pom.xml

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.12</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>${jwt.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>${postgres.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: попробуйте прописать в файл hosts (например: test.com) адрес по 127.0.0.1 и использовать его вместо localhost, очень вероятно причина в этом, т.к. localhost по умолчанию исключен из cors запросов так как не может по нормальному использоваться в заголовках запросов

Comment: @DaniilLoban, так 127.0.0.1 еквивалентно ip локального хоста

Comment: Эквивалентность тут не помеха вот [похожий ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56328474/origin-http-localhost4200-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-in-angular7). И еще из [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) "Говорят, что агент пользователя делает запрос с другого источника (cross-origin HTTP request), если источник текущего документа отличается от запрашиваемого ресурса доменом, протоколом или **портом**." Возможно, [пригодится](https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-rest-service-allow-cross-origin/)

Comment: Попробовал третий вариант из вашей ссылки. Добавил в hosts 127.0.0.1 local.mydomain.com. По этому адресу local.mydomain.com:4200 выдает ошибку "Invalid Host header", возможно надо что-то в Angular править. Но тогда проще по второму варианту пойти, настроить прокси

Comment: Настройка прокси тоже не помогла. Прямо мистика какая-то

Answer (score 0):

В бине CorsConfigurationSource нужно добавить
configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].